# bastion server with MFA

Tags: linux, ssh, google-authenticator, multi-factor-authentication

I have a bastion server with enabled MFA using google-authenticator service. But I cannot use proxycommand through my bastion:

```
> ssh -vvv -i ~/.ssh/file.pem  user@ip -o "proxycommand ssh -q -W %h:%p user@bastion"
OpenSSH_7.9p1 Ubuntu-10, OpenSSL 1.1.1b  26 Feb 2019
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname ip is address
debug1: Executing proxy command: exec ssh -q -W ip:22 user@bastion
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/file.pem type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/file.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.9p1 Ubuntu-10
Password: 
Verification code: 


connection exited by timeout
```

Is it possible to use proxycommand with MFA?

/etc/pam.d/common-session:

```
session [default=1]         pam_permit.so
session requisite           pam_deny.so
session required            pam_permit.so
session optional            pam_umask.so
session required    pam_unix.so 
session optional    pam_systemd.so 

auth required pam_google_authenticator.so nullok
```

/etc/ssh/sshd_config :

```
PubkeyAuthentication yes
PasswordAuthentication yes
ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes

UsePAM yes
X11Forwarding yes
PrintMotd no

AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
Subsystem   sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with firewall rules, proxycommand works with MFA!